# Is it possible to use AIDL without binding service to the activity

Tags: android, android-service, aidl

I've implemented and aidl file as follows:

```
interface ITaskService{
void addGetNamesJob();
void addUploadJob();
}
```

I then in my service have done the following:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return new ITaskService.Stub() {
        @Override
        public void addBeerNamesJob() throws RemoteException {
            jobManager.addJobInBackground(new GetNamesTask());
        }

    @Override
    public void addUploadJob() throws RemoteException {
        jobManager.addJobInBackground(new UploadRatingTask(wifi, twitter, TWITTER_CONSUMER, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET, /*ctx,*/ accessToken, accessTokenSecret ));
    }
};
}
```

then in my main activity the service is bound as follows:

```
private void initService() {
        Log.i(TAG, "initService()" );
        mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
                service = ITaskService.Stub.asInterface((IBinder)iBinder);
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
                bound = false;
                service = null;
            }
        };
        if(service == null){
            Intent it = new Intent();
            it.setAction("com.company.taskservice");
            bindService(it, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            bound = true;
        }
    }

    private void releaseService() {
        if(bound && mServiceConnection!=null && service!=null){
            unbindService(mServiceConnection);
        }
        bound = false;
        service = null;
        Log.d(TAG, "releaseService(): unbound.");
    }
```

This all works perfectly, I can call on the methods in the service via the interface.  However, what I would like to do now is on device boot is start the service, which I written like this:

```
public class DeviceBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent ratingUpload = new Intent(context, RatingUploaderService.class);
            //Toast.makeText(context, "------------->>>>DEVICE BOOT RECEIVER CALLED ---- CONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            context.startService(ratingUpload);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want the service to die if the app is A. sent to the background or B. killed.  So if it's possible to start the service on boot, it will run independently of the application.  However, can I through my aidl file access the methods without binding and if so can someone show me how?

thanks in advance

Comment: no,  aidl is for bound services only

Comment: thank you.  Can I ask if I wanted access to methods within a service, is it possible to do without aidl?

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: thanks but I don't want to bind the service as I mentioned in my question, I'm want to start the service on boot

Comment: if you want to "access to methods within a service" you have to bind to it, from where do you want to access your service?

Comment: I have a service with two methods, I have multiple fragments, I need to access these methods from within three of these fragments all of which are held by the main activity at different times

Comment: and what's wrong with the service binding? why don't you want to do that?

Comment: The methods I have are network dependent, I have it so that if there is no network that even if the app is killed the service will continue to check for connection and if there it picks up connection it performs certain tasks